# Change credentials or write the good connection string to a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am writing some test.

I want to connect to a database on a server and I use Visual Studio 2015 Community edition learning c#.

Following this guide: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272693%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

I open SQL Server object explorer and get to the server. But I notice that the connection is made with my actual credentials.

And so the connection string is:

```
Data Source=serverwiththedatabase;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;
```

I want to use `domain\domainuser` and password and just perform a select.

So should I change it in:

```
new SqlConnection("server=serverwiththedatabase;database=myDb;uid=domain\User;password=Pass;");
```

Comment: no, just leave it as it is and run your C# application as the domain user, the app will then authenticate using windows integrated security and you don't save any credentials in the connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important values in an connection string for an [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) are:

- `Data Source`: this is your database server name (not `server`!)
- `Initial catalog`: this is your database name (not `database`!)
- `Integrated Security`: `True` if you want to use windows authentication, `False` if you want SQL server authentication

AFAIK there are only these two options: windows or sql server. So if you set `Integrated Security` to `False`, you need to specify `UID`and `PWD`, which will be the credentials for a SQL server authentication. This user has to be defined in the SQL server's user management and has nothing to do with domain users.

If you use windows authentication, the connection is started with the user credentials of the calling process (which in your case will be your windows user credentials).

See [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on connection strings and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for adding users to a SQL server.

Comment: thank you very much, if i want to make a user that can only perform some selects on some views what property or roles should i grant?

Comment: Well that's another question and I'm not really good at the details of sql server user management. I would have to goolge and click through the management windows and find out myself. So maybe you want to open another question so that more experienced users can help you.